# Bind a Custom Entity Event to an Indexer ?

Tags: indexer

I have added an event for a custom entity to an Indexer but I have some issue:

- `_registerEvent()` is called correctly
- `_processEvent()` is never triggered

Here what I did:

In my `Indexer` Model I have add the Custom Entity/Event:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $_matchedEntities = array(
    MY_CUSTOM_ENTITY::ENTITY => array(
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE,
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_MASS_ACTION,
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_DELETE
    )
);
```

In the custom entity model I added the call to `logEvent()`

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    parent::_beforeSave();
    Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->logEvent(
        $this, self::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
    );
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I was missing is the call to `processEntityAction()`, this is usually done on the entity `_afterSave()` method.

```
protected function _afterSave()
{
    parent::_afterSave();
    Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
        $this, self::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
    );

    return $this;
}
```